# Issue with building makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I am trying to build a simple makefile for `c++` using `g++`. Even a simple makefile is not working on my computer (MacOS X). 
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) 
Create the same files and makefile. I just replaced `CC=gcc` to `CXX=g++`, in makefile2. I am using c++ format for files. 
I can compile it with `g++`, (in command line)

But when I try to make it by "make" command I get the following error.

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Format and directory are correct. 
Any help is appreciated.

Here is makefile:

```
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=-I.

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
    $(CXX) -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o
```

**"hellomake.cpp" :**

```
#include "hellomake.h"

int main() {
    // call a function in another file
    myPrintHelloMake();

    return(0);
}
```

**hellofunc.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hellomake.h"

void myPrintHelloMake(void) {

    printf("Hello makefiles!\n");

    return;
}
```

**hellomake.h**

```
/*
 example include file
 */

void myPrintHelloMake(void);
```

Comment: We would obviously need to see your makefile in order to help. And if you want to learn how to use make, the place you need to go is the GNU Make documentation.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I put link there. I used everything from there to test,

Comment: We don't do links. Post the content of your makefile inline with your question.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I added to the question

Comment: You will get that error if you invoke make in a directory that doesn't contain a makefile. Please investigate the concept of "current working directory".

Comment: It is in the same directory as the files are. I can compile them in command line. but makefile doesn't work.

Comment: *"It is in the same directory as the files are."* Presumably "It" here is the makefile. That's good. Next, is your commend line in the same directory as well. That is, if you type `ls` does it list makefile (and the source files)? Finally what is the name of the makefile? Is it one that `make` automatically identifiers? Bonus question: are there any other files there that `make` might identify as a makefile before noticing the one that you mean for it to use.

Comment: @dmckee yes, I am in the same directory as makefile and other files are. I typed `ls` it shows: `makefile.rtf` is it the correct format? the name is `makefile.rtf`

Comment: *"makefile.rtf"* That's your problem. Two problems, really. One that is not a name that `make` likes and two `make` is expecting a plain text file not rich text. You can force `make` to use any file with the `-f` option, but it is going to care about the format even then.

Comment: @dmckee which format should i use for makefile `.txt` ? What do you mean by it is not a name that `make` likes? which name shall i use?

Comment: The standard names for makefiles are `makefile` and `Makefile`.  No extension.  Some `make`s will look for others as well, but it's best to stick with one of the standard names unless you know exactly why it's to your advantage to do otherwise.  The *format* should be plain text, but that's an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger probably that's the issue, how can i create a file without any extension?

Comment: And your makefile should be in plain text (i.e. what you would mark `.txt` if you were using an extension), but old-school unixers didn't need no steenkin file extensions.

Comment: @Sarah What kind of system are you working on? If you're on a system that demands extensions your make probably expects `.txt`, but ... that's not very common these days.

Comment: Use a better editor?  Seriously, although some editors and utilities will suggest or even automatically add extensions, there is normally a way to configure file dialogs not to do that.  And if you can't figure that out, then you certainly should be able to rename the file after the fact to remove the extension.

Comment: @dmckee it is mac

Comment: the issue is solved. as you said, i used the plain text file. Thanks dmckee, and johnBollinger

Comment: Great. Unless you are using System 9 or earlier you are actually running a unix box and can use all those old tools exactly as they are meant to be used. No file extensions are needed. As an aside I prefer to install X11 and run an x-term to using the terminal program, but that's a detail.

Comment: @dmckee thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The issue was about `makefile` format. Initially it was `makefile.rtf`. Following comments I changed it to plain text (No extension) and the issue solved.